# Getting images from url in Table View asynchronously

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsurlconnection

So I am developing an app which contains a table view that has images in cells. I download all these images from a URL and store them in an array. I need to load these images asynchronously so I decided to use NSURLConnectionDataDelegate. I tried this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[URLsArray objectAtIndex:row]]];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if (theConnection) {
        receicedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed.");
    }
    return cell;
}
```

But it doesn't work. And I don't know what to write in:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

to set images to imageViews in cells. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would highly recommend using [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) simply because it takes care of these kind of concerns.

At the very least, take a look at their [`UIImageView` category](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.h) as it allows you to do this:

```
UIImageView *imgView = //alloc, get it from a nib, whatever;
[imgView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"StringPath"]];
```

Comment: But if I use setImageWithURL, it will load pictures synchronously, won't it? If yes, how to make it asynchronously?

Comment: if you follow the documentation link, you will see that it clearly states that the image will download asynchronously.

Comment: OK, but is there any way without using any additional libraries?

Comment: I'll let someone else post that answer. For me there is no reason not to lessen the pain of development by utilizing proven code that is freely available. No reason to reinvent the wheel. :) (Particularly when they can turn all your questions and code into a single line of code with `- setImageWithURL:`!)

Comment: It worked pretty well) Sorry for being so annoying, but I need an animating activity indicator instead while the picture is downloading. the method setImageWithURL:placeholderImage: allows showing an image, but I need an Activity Indicator. How shall this work?

Comment: I haven't personally used it but the library includes an activity indicator. Unfortunately, that also means I don't know what it looks like. See if [AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager](http://afnetworking.org/Documentation/Classes/AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager.html) suits your needs. Alternatively, I have also used  [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) which is pretty slick. Of course, there is also a built in activity indicator which I haven't used, so you're on your own there as well. If you want more details, you should probably make another question. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

For a simpler solution I would recommend using [Cached Image for iOS](http://www.speedyapi.com/index.php/posts/96-cached-image-for-ios). It's a simple piece of code that you can add to your xcode project, and it does what you need (+ support for caching).